# OBIEE Answers not showing results

Tags: oracle, oracle11g, business-intelligence, obiee

I recently installed OBIEE 11.1.1.6.0. I imported the repository I had from 11.1.1.5 which was working fine till now.

In the administration tool, I can query my data and update the rows, I can connect with the same credentials as the connection pool without problems in SQLPLUS.

Users have the RESOURCE and CONNECT privileges.

My weblogic user as all the privileges and has been granted read/write to my Subject area.
I have set the environment variables, modified the instancesconfig.xml and tried all the things i could've found on the OTN but BI Answers continues to give me this ERROR

```
View Display Error

Odbc driver returned an error (SQLExecDirectW).

Error Details

Error Codes: OPR4ONWY:U9IM8TAC:OI2DL65P

State: HY000. Code: 10058. [NQODBC] [SQL_STATE: HY000] 
[nQSError: 10058] A general error has occurred. 
[nQSError: 43113] Message returned from OBIS. 
[nQSError: 43119] Query Failed: 
[nQSError: 17001] Oracle Error code: 1017, message: ORA-01017: invalid username/password; logon denied at OCI call OCISessionBegin. 
[nQSError: 17014] Could not connect to Oracle database. (HY000)
SQL Issued: SELECT 0 s_0, "SAP_AVIS"."Fait SAP AVIS"."Avis" s_1 FROM "SAP_AVIS" FETCH FIRST 65001 ROWS ONLY
```

Please help, I am desperate.

Comment: Thanks APC for the layout. I am quite new so i don't know all the tricks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I have been able to resolve my OCI ORA-01017 error.

The problem was caused by my connection pools.

I had a connection amed "A" to access tables in a certain schema in my DB and another connection named "B" this time to access tables in another schema but in the same DB.

In Oracle BI Answers (presentation), I was trying to view data whitin the connection B but strangely OBIEE Answers was using the connection A.

In the end I removed/renamed the connection A and everthing worked like nothing never happend.

I am not saying that this is the best method. Maybe i skipped a config that assigns the default connection pool to use but it did the job.

Answer (score 0):

Option 1:
Copy your tnsnames.ora to {Oracle_BI1}\network\admin directory & {oracle_common}\network\admin directory

Option 2:
Instead of using tnsnames.ora entry in the RPD, use the full expanded tnsnames.

I have never faced this issue, so I'm not sure this'll work or not but you can try. Option 2 might just do the trick.

Vijay.

Comment: Thanks for the answer but I have resolved my issue. I had two connection pools named A and B. In answers i was trying to access table in B but for some strange reason it only used the first one(A). I deleted A and everything work fine

Answer (score 0):

For me oracle client was not installed,
when I Installed the oracle client problem got solved